# how to show first 2 and last 2 line of all the files whose name starts with “file”

Tags: 14.04, command-line

**how to show first 2 and last 2 line of all the files whose name starts with “file”.** with Command in ubuntu

Comment: Please note that I provided my answer because I wanted to figure out how to do it myself. You will get better answers on future questions if you put in more effort to describe the issue and do your own research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify exactly how to do this, so here are two ways:

1. Print the first two lines of all the files, then the last two lines of all the files.

   ```
   head --lines=2 file*
   tail --lines=2 file*
   ```
2. Print the first two lines then the last two lines of each file in sequence.

   ```
   for file in file*; do
       head --lines=2 "$file"
       tail --lines=2 "$file"
   done
   ```